# Prove that (possibly) infinite group of all invertible maps of X to itself is not Abelian.

Tags: group-theory, functions, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

I have this question on my assignment and I this fact seems trivial to me, but I can not come up with a rigorous proof.
I thought to go by contradiction:

Assume such a group $G$ is Abelian -> $\forall f,g \in G:f \circ g=g \circ f $. Then $\forall x_i \in G: f(g(x_i) = g(f(x_i)$. $

It implies that if $\exists x_n,x_m \in G: g(x_i) =  x_n, f(x_i) = x_m \rightarrow  g(x_m) = f(x_n)$, which is the case only if $g = f^{-1}$, but that is obviously not always the case.

Need some pointer to wrap this up in a formal proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has at least $3$ elements, then the group of all invertible maps on $X$ contains $S_3$, which is not abelian.

Concretely, let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be three distinct elements of $X$.
Then the map that swaps $x_1$ and $x_2$ does not commute with the map that swaps $x_1$ and $x_3$.

Comment: I guess this one is a smarter one. Anyways, what do you think of my way of thought, can it also have a place?

Comment: @tmac_balla, you seem to be trying to prove that no two maps commute, but this is neither true nor needed. You only have to show an example of two maps that do not commute.

Comment: I actually was trying to say that it is not always the case that they are commutable because it can be that g(x_m) != f(x_n)